# How to auto increment xml file version

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an XML file which I want to increment the version number each time the user clicks `btnNewfile`.

It must start from `1000` and increment to by `1`. I am also confused on which version must increment or both. The problem is the format when I try to debug I get this error:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

How can I increment it?

XML:

```
<resheader name="version">
<value>2.0</value>
</resheader>
```

What I have tried:

```
private void btnNewfile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    int current = 1000;
    current++;
    var versionNumber = doc.Descendants("value").FirstOrDefault();
    current = (int)versionNumber;
    versionNumber.SetValue(current + 1); //error here;Input string was not in a correct format.
    lbl_Output_Version.Text = versionNumber.ToString();
}
```

The problem comes here as I have these two:

```
<resheader name="resmimetype">text/microsoft-resx</resheader>
<resheader name="version">2.0</resheader> // i only want to update this one
```

When I debug it is getting the first one with `"text/microsoft-resx"` and it throws error after that.

Comment: Input string was not in a correct format.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `decimal` instead of an `int`, since your string contains `.0`. Also you need to get the `Value`, not the entire element to convert. You can also use `Where` to select the exact item you want.

```
XElement versionNumber = doc.Descendants("resheader")
                            .Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == "version")
                            .Descendants("value")
                            .First();

decimal current = Convert.ToDecimal(versionNumber.Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

versionNumber.SetValue(Math.Max(1000, current + 1));
```

Since you wanted to start at `1000`, I added a `Math.Max`.

Comment: let me try and i will get back to you soon

Comment: It is getting the values from this one <resheader name="resmimetype">text/microsoft-resx</resheader>  and it throws the error of incorect string  format

Comment: your answer seem to be correct but i need to be sure as now my things behaving abnormal when writing to the file, it is creating newdataset with <Table1> of which is wrong and hence i can't load the file after creating it. it throws an error saying cannot find table 2

Comment: Not sure, but it seems unrelated to this question. I suggest to create a new question with all the info necessary to reproduce this.

Comment: owk have a look on my new question please. i have to accept your answer after loading the file to see

Comment: chect it out. sorry i had to wait for 40 minutes to post a question again  @ Patrick Hofman

Comment: the value stays 1000 with no changes

Comment: I have fixed my problem and it is not updating. it throws an error ;Object reference not set to an instance of an object. on this line ;decimal current = Convert.ToDecimal(versionNumber.Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: @ITForward: So version number is null. It doesn't have a value for `name = version`. Try to put an `if` statement around it.

Comment: XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                XDocument xd = new XDocument(doc);
                XElement versionNumber = xd.Descendants("resheader")
                            .Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == "version")
                            .Descendants("value")
                            .FirstOrDefault();

                decimal current = Convert.ToDecimal(versionNumber.Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                versionNumber.SetValue(Math.Max(1000, current + 1));

Comment: @ITForward: Nice copy of my answer. What is your question? Did the `if` help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72218/discussion-between-it-forward-and-patrick-hofman).